# Sonarqube 5.6.3 Blame for SVN fails with error 500

Tags: svn, jenkins, sonarqube, maven-3

Our environment:

- Sonarqube 5.6.3
- Jenkins 2.7
- Maven 3.3.9
- Java 1.8

After upgrading to Sonarqube 5.6.3 we experience an error with the Blame functionality for the SVN plugin when running the `mvn sonar:sonar`, the log shows this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project test: Error when executing blame for file pom.xml: svn: E175002: OPTIONS of '/repos/java/test/maven-test/trunk/pom.xml': 500 Internal Server Error (https://fssvn.evry.com)
[ERROR] svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/repos/java/test/maven-test/trunk/pom.xml'
```

The strangest thing here is that it worked for a while, and then after some time (month?)  failed. We have not upgraded anything in our environment that would affect this as far as I know, but you never know. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: It looks like it's the SVN server returning the 500. Anything in the logs on that side?

Comment: It seems to generate an error that we have had in our SVN repos for some time, but I havent found the solution to this :[Tue Jan 10 16:06:44.580376 2017] [authn_core:error] [pid 33058] [client 10.252.224.35:53218] AH01796: AuthType Basic configured without corresponding module

Comment: The strange thing is that the Blame functionality did work for some time, and all other SVN operations work too!